# android fragment when to create and dispose unmanaged resources

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I use a System.Threading.Timer in a Textchanged event of a Searchview inside a fragment.

```
    System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private void SearchView_QueryTextChange(object sender, Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Change(300, Timeout.Infinite);
        ...
        ...
    }

    public override void OnResume()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(MyCallBack);
        base.OnResume();
    }

    public override void OnPause()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
        base.OnPause();
    }
```

I instantiate the timer when onResume is called and dispose (free resources) it when onPause is called.
The problem is that if I click 'home' button the timer is disposed (onPause) but after clicking again the app then onResume is not called. When I try to type in the searchView the timer is disposed.

In which method of the Fragment should I instantiate the unmanaged resource (onstart,oncreateview, onResume...) and when to dispose it (onStop,onpause, onDestroy...) so I'm not creating multiple timers(leaking)?
What is the proper way?

Comment: onStart/onStop is a safer bet, although it depends on what your timer is doing. Should it stop if the app is put to background? Because if no, then `onViewCreated/onDestroyView`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks. I use the timer to produce a small delay while I'm typing in searchview box. It should not execute after the app is not visible.

Comment: Then it's `onStart/onStop`

Answer (score 0):

As EpicPandaForce's said, `onStart/onStop` is better way.

For safety,from your code When entering the Avtivity multiple times, `_timer` may be created repeatedly.Coding as follow will be safe.

```
public override void OnResume()/OnStart()
{
    if(null != _timer)
    {
         _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(MyCallBack);
         base.OnResume();
    }
}

public override void OnPause()/OnStop()
{
    if(null != _timer)
    {
       _timer.Dispose();       
    }
    base.OnPause();
}
```

Another (`System.Timers.Timer`)Timer is recommended. You can create once in `OnCreate()` Method.And later control using it in other method.

```
 System.Timers.Timer timer

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        //Do something
    };
}

public override void OnResume()/OnStart()
{
    timer.Start();
    base.OnResume();
}

public override void OnPause()/OnStop()
{
    timer.Stop();
    base.OnPause();
}
```